# Jquery Animation lags/stutters

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm working on a new intro page for my site and ran into an issue...

The logo rotates, stops at 0 degrees, and should then scale to 20% and move to top right.

After the rotate stops, it has like a 1.2 second pause before rapidly resizing the item and continuing...

Can someone take a look and see what's going on?

**Code** (**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3KJ3/)**)

```
rotate = function(element,initial){
  element = $(element);
  rDeg = initial; //Initial angle
  element.css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rDeg+'deg)',
       '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rDeg+'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+rDeg+'deg)',
         '-o-transform': 'rotate('+rDeg+'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate('+rDeg+'deg)'      
  });
    // Animate rotation with a recursive call
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        ++rDeg; rotate('#logo',rDeg);
      },5); 
        if(rDeg==-1){ clearTimeout(timer); moveLogo() }
}
rotate('#logo',-80);

moveLogo = function(){ $('#logo').animate({width:'20%'}, 1800) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is propably caused by animate changing width from 100% to 20% (and it's not having an effect until the width is less than 200px). Try this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v3KJ3/4/)

```
moveLogo = function(){
    var requiredWidth = $(window).width() / 5;
    $("#logo").animate({width:requiredWidth + 'px'}, 1800);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. but I don't want it to delay.. I want it to tween the animation for 1.8 seconds to make it smooth.

Comment: Am I going to have to do something similar (looping, gradually changing value) to make the animation fluid? I thought that's what the `duration` value was for. It's always worked before. *Well, always in Chrome, not always smooth in FF*

Comment: In the updated demo I shrink it to the required size in pixels and then apply "width: 20%". You can use "%" too, but it does not combine well with `max-width`, which will take precedence over `width`.

Comment: Interesting... Even without max-width (added for fiddle) it had the error. I've ran into problems with using percents before, but didn't really think it would matter here. Since it works, it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use a jquery plugin like [this](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) this will resolve the recursive function that you are creating for a simple `$('#logo').rotate(90);` at the same time you should add your resize function `$('#logo').animate({width:'20%'}` so both are gonna do at the same time for a nice resize and location. Hope this can help you.